# regex matching for lines from file

Tags: regex, shell

I have a file that reads something like below:

```
Change 305034 on 2017/04/26 by jdoe@BP
Change 304966 on 2017/04/26 by adoe@adoe
Change 304880 on 2017/04/25 by cm@cpu_jar_process_main_8.30.0.9
Change 304843 on 2017/04/25 by mdoe@BP
```

I need to pick lines that has `cm@` in it. I have generated a regex to match it.

```
Change\s[0-9]+\son\s[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\sby\scm
```

I have tested it `https://regex101.com/` and it works fine.

Now I want to use a shell script to do the matching. The script is as follows-

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    # echo "Text read from file: $line"
    # Change\s[0-9]+\son\s[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\sby\scm"
    if [[ "$line" =~ "Change\s[0-9]+\son\s[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\sby\scm" ]]; then
        echo $line
    fi

done < "output.txt"
```

But it does not match any line.

I found that if i use `if [[ "$line" =~ "Change" ]]; then` it is returning results. But no results when I use the full regex pattern. I am assuming that there is a syntax error.

Can someone point out what is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: _I have tested it https://regex101.com/ and it works fine_ - this tool is **not** designed to test bash regular expressions.

Comment: @TomFenech Could you point me to any online/offline tool that can be used to test bash regex?

Comment: I'm not aware of any but I wouldn't be surprised if one existed!

Answer (score 2):

If your input file contains lines in similar format like `Change 305034 on 2017/04/26 by ...` - there's pretty short ***awk*** solution:

```
awk '$6~/^cm@/' output.txt
```

The output:

```
Change 304880 on 2017/04/25 by cm@cpu_jar_process_main_8.30.0.9
```

Comment: This works but I need to look through the file one line at a time and get the results as there will be different actions based on what matched and what did not.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [[ "$line" =~ 'Change\s[0-9]+\son\s[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\sby\scm' ]]; then
                 ^                                                        ^
                 |                                                        |
                  `- Use single quotes to avoid escaping interpretation  -'
```